# Get selected value to use in if statement

Tags: json, node.js, angularjs-scope, pug, mean-stack

I'm trying to validate the content inside a select dropdown using ngoptions and ngchange.
For example, if the content on selected is 'Ticket' then a it will show the submit button.

Currently I've got, in my view (front-end) with Jade:

```
Select(ng-model='angReporting' ng-options="r.reporting for r in 
incategory" style="width:100px;" ng-change="ifChange(angReporting)" )
br
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm(ng-click="incidentsCreate()" ng-hide="validate(status)") 
Submit
```

The above is a short example, I've got a set of chained selects (angularjs) working.
To validate that the correct content is selected I've got on my module the following:

$scope.itemList=[];

```
$scope.ifChange=function(item){
    $scope.itemList.push(item.reporting);

    for (var i=0; i < $scope.itemList.length; i++){
      if($scope.itemList[i] === 'Ticket'){
        $scope.validate = {status: false};
      }
    }
  };
```

The json content for the scopes is, in short:

```
 $scope.incategory = [
    {

      'reporting':'Incident',
      'content':[
        {
          ...
        }
      'reporting':'Ticket',
      'content':[
        {
          ...
        }
```

Thanks in advance for sharing your ideas
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"angReporting" is not defined when you do:

```
ng-change="ifChange(angReporting)"
```

You can get the ng-model "angReporting" value on the controller side with "$scope.angReporting" so I would sugest the following:

controller

```
$scope.incategory = [
    {
      'reporting':'Incident',
      'content':''
    },
    {
      'reporting':'Ticket',
      'content':''
    }];
$scope.itemList = [];
  $scope.ifChange=function(){
    $scope.itemList.push($scope.angReporting.reporting);
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.itemList.length; i++){
      if($scope.itemList[i] === 'Ticket'){
        $scope.validate = true;
      }
    }
  };
```

View

```
Select(ng-model='angReporting' ng-options="r.reporting for r in incategory" ng-change="ifChange()" )
br
a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm(ng-click="incidentsCreate()" ng-show="validate") Submit
```